# Object of type 'InlineKeyboardButton' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

my code is here

```
def forwards(update:Update, context:CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    next_index = int(query.data.split("_")[1]) + 1
    current_index = int(query.data.split("_")[1])
    html = ""

   # if context.user_data["totalPage"] == current_index:
    for i in range(((current_index - 1)*20), context.user_data["rows"]):
        html += context.user_data["videos"][i]
    c_d = current_index - 1
    button = [[InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️previous page", callback_data="minus_" + str(c_d))]]
    markup = InlineKeyboardButton(button)
    a = query.edit_message_text(text = html, parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML, reply_markup = markup) 


def message_handle(update, context:CallbackContext):
    temp = r.message_handler(update.message)
    context.user_data["videos"] = temp["videos"]
    context.user_data["totalPage"] = temp["totalPage"]
    context.user_data["rows"] = temp["rows"]
    html = ""
    
    if temp["rows"] >= 20:
        count = 0
        for i in temp["videos"]:
            if count == 20:
                break
            html += i
            count += 1
    elif temp["rows"] < 20:
        for i in temp["videos"]:
            html += i
        
    button = [[InlineKeyboardButton("next page➡️", callback_data="plus_2")]]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
    
    update.message.reply_text(text = html , parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML, 
                                disable_web_page_preview = True, 
                                reply_to_message_id = update.message.message_id,
                                reply_markup = markup)
```

when cliecnt sends a keyword to the bot, the bot ,using the keyword, finds out relevant data in the other file, txtfile.
It will forward reply message to the client page by page , using callbackquery .

there are 3 function,

1. def message_handle (that's for MessageHandler)

2.def forwards ( thats for callbackQuery handler, as the name said for forward page after "forward"( callback_data "plus" )button click)

3. def backwards ( for callbackQuery handler, as the name said for backward page after "backward"(callback data "minus") button click)

um...
the message_handle shows (in function message_handle) fine..
but there is error showed after the inline button(forward) click..

```
TypeError: Object of type 'InlineKeyboardButton' is not JSON serializable
```

and the following is the main part

```
def main():
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, message_handle))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(forwards, pattern = "plus"))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(backwards, pattern = "minus"))
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

so whats wrong of it..?
thanks for you attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is just what the error you are getting says it is.  You are attempting to include an instance of the `InlineKeyboardButton` class in a message.  A message is a serialized string of bytes.  So to send that instance as part of the message, it has to be serialized.  Apparently, `InlineKeyboardButton`  is not serializable.  This means that the class has fields that can't be represented in JSON.  Looking quickly at the docs for that object, I see that when constructed, it can take callback function references.  That could be the problem.  A function reference isn't serializable.  It could be due to some other similar issue.  You generally don't want to try to send a complex object like that in a message, or otherwise attempt to serialize it.

My guess is that you don't want to send that object, but rather send some of the data encapsulated in that object.  I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, nor am I familiar with the message passing mechanism you are using, but the idea of sending a button in a message doesn't generally make sense.  I would rethink just what data you want to put in your message, and make sure that it all consists of simple values (strings, numbers, etc.) that can be serialized into a JSON structure.

Comment: .... I can't stop lmao...

I just mess up that.. there should be InlineKeyboardMarkup.. but i type InlineKeyBoardButton...XDD

thank you so much your attention.!

Comment: ha!  I'm laughing too.  It makes sense that this was just a simple mistake.